# An unreachable statement error

Tags: unreachable-statement

I don't know from where the error is coming "unreachable statement[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAOXy.png)"

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless, as are pictures of your entire desktop. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `return` statement before `if` statement. If you return, how will your `if` statement be executed. Hence `if` become unreachable.

Remove this line:

```
return new String[0];
```